# The set of all finite sequences in RCA0

Tags: peano-axioms, second-order-logic, reverse-math

In the book "subsystems of second order arithmetic", page 68, Simpson claimed that the set of all codes of finite sequences (denoted by "Seq") exists by sigma 0-0 comprehension. I tried to write a sigma 0-0 formula like A(t)
to express that t is code of a finite sequence, but I failed. The only formula I could write was the formula that using existential set quantifier. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: You should be able to bound everything by the code $t$ itself. E.g. if $t$ is a code for a sequence, then the length of that sequence and each term of that sequence is smaller than $t$. (This might have finitely many exceptions, but those can be explicitly treated - e.g. maybe we need $t>2$.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber thanks. But if we want to say that t is a code of a sequence X, the natural way is to use "∃X such that...". How can I get rid of this existential set quantifier?

Comment: That's not the natural way to do it. $X$ ranges over *possibly infinite sets*, not *finite sequences*. Forget about second-order quantifiers entirely, this is just "Godel-style" thinking: how would you talk about finite sequences in **first-order** arithmetic? For example (I'm not sure which method Simpson uses), think about representing the string $$\langle 13,4,65,0\rangle$$ by the number $$2^{13+1}3^{4+1}5^{65+1}7^{0+1}.$$ This generalizes to an appropriate coding system for all strings.

Comment: If we use the method I just outlined, we have $x\in \mathsf{Seq}$ iff whenever $p,q$ are primes with $p<q$ and $q\vert x$ we also have $p\vert x$. Do you see why? Now prima facie that's $\Sigma^0_1$ ... but of course we can restrict attention to $p,q\color{red}{<x}$ to make it $\Sigma^0_0$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes I understand. Thanks.
Simpson proved this:
for any finite set X, there is three natural number k,m,n such that for all i, i∈X  iff  i<k and m(i+1)+1 divides n.
then Code (X) is the least (k,(m,n)). 
By this coding, how can I express t∈Seq?